# Listview data refresh in asp.net with c#

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have asp.net website. I am showing data in ListView control from database and everything working fine.

finally ,i added search button to search from the database and i want to show the result in the same ListView.

my question is : how i can refresh my ListView with search results ??

thanks in advance,

Comment: please post your code and HTML

Answer (score 1):

Hoping that you can implement the steps easily in the code.

1. Create an click event for the search button
2. In the Click event (Code behind file) write the code to search for data in the database as per your search criteria.
3. Assign the searched data to the ListView (using ListviewId.DataSource)
4. Call DataBind() function of ListView (It will bind the searched data with LisView)

That's all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the above steps working when we call data to the listview in the first time , but when we want to refresh listview data with new data that's not working.